# Forcing longtables width exacly within text width

Tags: margins, longtable

I've been looking for solutions of this problem but I only found solutions that uses `small` or `footnotesize` for table font letters, or `\setlength\tabcolsep` for columns width adjustment. But these solutions doesnt fit automatically the table width into text width and `\resizebox` doesnt work for longtables enviorment. So, what can I do here?

obs: I also put an table written in table environment fitted by `\resizebox` for sake of width comparation.

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
   \usepackage{float}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %CODE
   \usepackage{uarial}% FOR
   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% ARIAL FONT
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage[top=2cm,left=2cm,right=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
   \parindent=1.5cm
   \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][c]{%
   \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
    \begin{document}
        \newpage
         \begin{table}[H]    
         \begin{center}  

        \caption{Lista dos amortecimentos mínimos para cada ponto de operação em relação diferentes sistemas de controle operando}
        \label{zetas}
        \vspace{-0.2cm}
        \resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
            \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
                \hline  \specialcell{ Condição \\ operativa} & \specialcell{ PSSs locais\\ \centering{$\zeta_{min} (\%) $}}  & \specialcell{ PSSs locais + PSS central \\ \centering{$\zeta_{min} (\%) $}}   & \specialcell{ PSSs locais + PSS central ordem reduzida\\  \centering{$\zeta_{min} (\%) $} } \\ 
                \hline Ponto 1& 15.59  & 40.80 & 28.19 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 2& 15.59 & 38.83 &  27.98 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 3& 15.63 & 41.48 &  27.71 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 4& 15.77 & 36.19 &  29.06\\ 
                \hline Ponto 5& 15.71 & 41.47 &  27.26\\ 
                \hline Ponto 6& 15.92 & 36.70 &  27.57\\ 
                \hline Ponto 7& 16.13 & 40.18 &  28.34\\ 
                \hline Ponto 8& 16.21 & 35.80 &  27.34\\ 
                \hline Ponto 9& 15.75 & 40.95 &  27.08\\ 
                \hline Ponto 10& 15.89& 35.21 &  29.18\\ 
                \hline Ponto 11& 16.20 & 33.60 & 29.30 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 12& 15.81 & 40.36 & 26.84 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 13& 16.89 & 34.40 & 26.87 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 14& 18.16 & 43.44 & 34.15 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 15& 23.74 & 37.72 & 30.89 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 16& 17.10 & 38.15 & 28.71 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 17& 19.51 & 30.68 & 25.64 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 18& 15.53 & 26.82 & 23.00 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 19& 12.56 & 34.74 & 26.83 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 20& 19.33 & 37.94 & 31.92 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 21& 20.07 & 37.21 & 35.49 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 22& 15.62 & 38.39 & 28.66 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 23& 15.67 & 37.94 & 25.93 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 24& 15.72 & 37.75 & 25.61 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 25& 15.76 & 37.99 & 25.41 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 26& 15.69 & 31.47 & 26.37 \\ 
                \hline Ponto 27& 17.35 & 29.22 & 25.28 \\ 
                \hline 
            \end{tabular} 
            %
        }   \end{center}

    \end{table} \vspace{-1.4cm}
    \footnotesize
\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}    
        \caption{Lista dos amortecimentos mínimos para cada ponto de operação em relação diferentes sistemas de controle operando}
        \label{table1}\\
            \hline   \specialcell{ Condição \\ operativa} & \specialcell{ PSSs locais\\ \centering{$\zeta_{min} (\%) $}}  & \specialcell{ PSSs locais + PSS central \\ \centering{$\zeta_{min} (\%) $}}   & \specialcell{ PSSs locais + PSS central ordem reduzida\\  \centering{$\zeta_{min} (\%) $} } \\ 
            \hline Ponto 1& 15.59  & 40.80 & 28.19 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 2& 15.59 & 38.83 &  27.98 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 3& 15.63 & 41.48 &  27.71 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 4& 15.77 & 36.19 &  29.06\\ 
            \hline Ponto 5& 15.71 & 41.47 &  27.26\\ 
            \hline Ponto 6& 15.92 & 36.70 &  27.57\\ 
            \hline Ponto 7& 16.13 & 40.18 &  28.34\\ 
            \hline Ponto 8& 16.21 & 35.80 &  27.34\\ 
            \hline Ponto 9& 15.75 & 40.95 &  27.08\\ 
            \hline Ponto 10& 15.89& 35.21 &  29.18\\ 
            \hline Ponto 11& 16.20 & 33.60 & 29.30 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 12& 15.81 & 40.36 & 26.84 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 13& 16.89 & 34.40 & 26.87 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 14& 18.16 & 43.44 & 34.15 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 15& 23.74 & 37.72 & 30.89 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 16& 17.10 & 38.15 & 28.71 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 17& 19.51 & 30.68 & 25.64 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 18& 15.53 & 26.82 & 23.00 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 19& 12.56 & 34.74 & 26.83 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 20& 19.33 & 37.94 & 31.92 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 21& 20.07 & 37.21 & 35.49 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 22& 15.62 & 38.39 & 28.66 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 23& 15.67 & 37.94 & 25.93 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 24& 15.72 & 37.75 & 25.61 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 25& 15.76 & 37.99 & 25.41 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 26& 15.69 & 31.47 & 26.37 \\ 
            \hline Ponto 27& 17.35 & 29.22 & 25.28 \\ 
            \hline 
\end{longtable} 
 \end{document}
```

Comment: You can make the table take the width, but it will not adjust the size of its contents e.g. the font will be `\small` or `\footnotesize` or whatever. Is that what you want? Resizing a table with `\resizebox` is evil anyway, so you shouldn't want to do it that way ;).

Answer (score 2):

Some suggestions:

- Never use `\resizebox` for tables -- unless you want to risk creating major font size changes between the text and table portions of your document and from one table to the next.
- Instead, provide a bit more structure to the table headers, e.g., through well-chosen line breaks. That way, the overall width of the table won't exceed `\textwidth` to begin with.
- Do give your tables a more "open" look by omitting all vertical bars and most horizontal bars. For the few remaining horizontal lines, don't use `\hline`. Instead, use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package to generate well-spaced lines.
- If you still want the width of a `longtable` environment to equal the width of the text block, use the method explained on p. 7 of the user guide of the longtable package; see also below.

[image]

```
   \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
   \usepackage{booktabs}
   \usepackage{graphicx}
   \usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %CODE
   \usepackage{helvet}% FOR
   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}% ARIAL FONT
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
   \parindent=1.5cm
   \newcommand{\specialcell}[2][t]{%
      \begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \begin{document}

\setlength\LTleft{0pt} % see p. 7 of longtable package user guide
\setlength\LTright{0pt}
\begin{longtable}{@{} l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} ccc @{}}    
\caption{Lista dos amortecimentos mínimos para cada ponto de operação em relação diferentes sistemas de controle operando}
\label{table1}\\
\toprule
\specialcell{Condição \\ operativa} & 
\specialcell{PSSs locais\\ \\ $\zeta_{\min}$ (\%) }  & 
\specialcell{PSSs locais + \\ PSS central \\ $\zeta_{\min}$ (\%) }   & 
\specialcell{PSSs locais + \\ PSS central ordem reduzida \\ $\zeta_{\min}$ (\%) } \\ 
\midrule
\endhead
\bottomrule
\endfoot
Ponto 1& 15.59  & 40.80 & 28.19 \\ 
Ponto 2& 15.59 & 38.83 &  27.98 \\ 
Ponto 3& 15.63 & 41.48 &  27.71 \\ 
Ponto 4& 15.77 & 36.19 &  29.06\\ 
Ponto 5& 15.71 & 41.47 &  27.26\\ \addlinespace
Ponto 6& 15.92 & 36.70 &  27.57\\ 
Ponto 7& 16.13 & 40.18 &  28.34\\ 
Ponto 8& 16.21 & 35.80 &  27.34\\ 
Ponto 9& 15.75 & 40.95 &  27.08\\ 
Ponto 10& 15.89& 35.21 &  29.18\\ \addlinespace
Ponto 11& 16.20 & 33.60 & 29.30 \\ 
Ponto 12& 15.81 & 40.36 & 26.84 \\ 
Ponto 13& 16.89 & 34.40 & 26.87 \\ 
Ponto 14& 18.16 & 43.44 & 34.15 \\ 
Ponto 15& 23.74 & 37.72 & 30.89 \\ \addlinespace
Ponto 16& 17.10 & 38.15 & 28.71 \\ 
Ponto 17& 19.51 & 30.68 & 25.64 \\ 
Ponto 18& 15.53 & 26.82 & 23.00 \\ 
Ponto 19& 12.56 & 34.74 & 26.83 \\ 
Ponto 20& 19.33 & 37.94 & 31.92 \\ \addlinespace
Ponto 21& 20.07 & 37.21 & 35.49 \\ 
Ponto 22& 15.62 & 38.39 & 28.66 \\ 
Ponto 23& 15.67 & 37.94 & 25.93 \\ 
Ponto 24& 15.72 & 37.75 & 25.61 \\ 
Ponto 25& 15.76 & 37.99 & 25.41 \\ \addlinespace
Ponto 26& 15.69 & 31.47 & 26.37 \\ 
Ponto 27& 17.35 & 29.22 & 25.28 \\ 
\end{longtable} 
\end{document}
```